# Unable to load HMAC_SHA1 plugin

Tags: perl, sha1, digest-authentication, hmacsha1

Running the Twitter Application in Perl and facing the above mentioned problem. The Perl is 5.8.8 and system is AIX with no root access.

Code

```
./p_t.pl
```

Error

> Unable to load HMAC_SHA1 plugin at
>   /vv/mm/tt/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Twitter/Lite.pm    line 192

Hwoever

```
cpan Digest::HMAC_SHA1
```

is running fine.

O/P

> Digest::HMAC_SHA1 is up to date (1.03).

and SHA1 is not running properly

```
cpan
force install Digest::SHA1
```

> Running make test   Can't test without successful make Running make
>   install   Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
>   Failed during this command:  GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz
>   : make NO

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an ancient post, but it's high on google, so this advice may eventually reach someone who can use it.

I was fighting with a similar issue, and it turned out my perl distribution did not include integer.pm (part of the distro) and I fixed said bug.

To check if this, or something similar, causes problems in your case, run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Digest::HMAC_SHA1;
```

And check what it fails on.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I have left Perl now and thinking for forever... But might be useful for someone.....